# Работа с определенным href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, проблема такая есть меню оно всегда одинаковое и отличается только ссылками

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb pull-left">

    <li><a href="/video/">Видео</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sdfsdf/">ыаыва</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ываыва</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ываыа</a></li>
    <li><a href="/osdfdf/">ыаыва</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ываыва</a></li>
    <li><a href="/ffdsdf/">ыавыаыв</a></li>

</ul>
```

мне нужно сделать так что б где меню видео появилось модальное окно а в нем iframe я делаю так но не работает

```js
$(function() { 
$( ".breadcrumb li a" ).click(function( event ) {
 if  ($(this).attr('href') === "http://example.com/video/"){
  event.preventDefault();                
                    $.ajax({  
                    url: "/video/iframe.html",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                     $("#content-video-width").show();  
                        $("#content-video").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
             }
                  
            });  
});
```

ошибок не выдает просто делает переход на страницу, еще раз мне надо чтобы другие ссылки делали переход, а именно эта нет она должна открыть модальное окно в котором iframe

Comment: что значит вот эта строка `$(this).attr('href') === "http://example.com/video/"` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский извиняюсь исправил, это для условия if

Comment: тогда может в условии надо писать `$(this).attr('href') === "/video/"` ?

Comment: `return false` в конце условия поставьте

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо . Заработало только понять не могу почему в consol.log пишет ссылку целиком. А так работает спасибо

Comment: @Vadim я не знаю как вы в консоль выводили.... ибо если даже на этом сайта в консоли набрать `$('.-list .-item._current a').attr('href')`, то выведет `/questions` ......возможно вы смотрели какой-нибудь `location.href`